# Hiding the MainWindow in WPF from an UserControl MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Before you guys mark it as a duplicate, please read the question below. I've included the other threads to show what I've tried.

I have a WPF application developed using MVVM pattern. It has a MainWindow and a few UserControls inside it.  When a Button is Clicked in one of the UserControls, I open a new Window. But before I do that, I have to hide the MainWindow first. I tried the following ways to do it, but it didn't work:

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

App.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
```

I also tried to set the Visibility property in XAML like this:

```
    <Window.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="MainDisplayVisible" Mode="TwoWay" Converter="{StaticResource boolConverter}"></Binding>
    </Window.Visibility>
```

And I looked online for help and tried what is mentioned in these links:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988149/i-cant-hide-the-window-in-mvvm)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362265/how-to-hide-a-window-using-mvvm)

None of these work for me. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Glenn.

Comment: as far as i know you cannot hide a main window, this is why its called "Main"

Comment: What does "didn't work" actually mean? What happens when you set the `App.Current.MainWindow.Visibility` property?

Comment: @mm8: The window stayed up. I saw that the property was false, but the window stayed open.

Comment: Do you have more than one window?

Comment: @mm8: Yes. From the UserControl in the MainWindow, I open a new window.

Comment: @mm8: I didn't get you. When I open the second window, I want to hide the MainWindow first.

Comment: I have used this.Hide(); from within the main windows .cs file and this worked for me but "App.Current.MainWindow.Hide();" should achieve the same result

Comment: It depends on which window that is the MainWindow.

Comment: @mm8: How do you determine that?

Comment: That was also for the main window

Comment: @Glenn: Put a breakpoint in your code and evaulate the value of `App.Current.MainWindow` just before you try to hide the window.

Comment: @mm8: when I put a breakpoint there, it shows : "MyApp.MainWindow"

Comment: Have you cast the window to MainWindow (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow), this may main seem counter intuitive but the your local definition for the main window is different

Comment: @stuicidle: I tried this:

`MainWindow window = (MyApp.MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow;
window.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;`

It didn't work.

Comment: do you have a sample app available?

Comment: @KundanVuppala: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: try these:
            using System.Windows;
            (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).Hide();
            (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
if they dont work you somewhere handle the event yourself in a wrong manner

Comment: @DenisSchaf: Sorry, that didn't work either. When you say, I'm not handling the event in a right way, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: make a new project and run this code. It will work. It does not work in your application..the only logical explanation is: a) you are not trying to close the MainWindow, but anoter window or b) You  are handeling or overwriting the onclosing event or any comparable event yourself in the code behind